# How to remove multiple events called from multiple function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written script to upload images and for that, I've written a single deleting function which I've called from two functions and whenever I call the deleting function from another function, it triggered at twice. 

For Ex:

```
function getImgTrashEvents(){
  $('.image-demo').bind().click(function(){
    if(confirm("Do you want to delete this image?")){
      //Do something to delete image
    }
  });
}

//Showing images from database
function showPresentImages(){
  //Here I've written ajax call to get all images 
  $.ajax({ 
    url:'get-images', 
    success: function(response){
      //Do something to load UI of images and delete button <img class="image-demo">
      getImgTrashEvents();
    }
  });
}

//Uploading new images
function uploadImages(){
  //demo ajax call to upload photo 
  $.ajax({
    url:'upload-photo',
    success: function(response){ 
      //Load UI with newly uploaded images with class images-demo
      getImgTrashEvents();
    }
  });
}
```

In this code, I've written 3 functions one is for getting all events of trash image, a second function for showing preset images from database and final function for uploading new images.

Here I am calling `getImgTrashEvents();` this function in both functions. But when I call it from both the events from `getImgTrashEvents();` are calling twice or more for single click after uploading an image and showing confirm alert twice. And if I call this function in only `showPresentImages()` function then it's not taking effect for `uploadImages()`.

Comment: You need to unbind the click event. before binding a new one. `$('.image-demo').unbind("click").click(function(){`

Comment: Why are you adding the click handlers every time you make an AJAX call? If you're trying to add handlers to dynamically-added elements, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @Barmar Because it's not taking effect.

Comment: If you did proper event delegation it would take effect.

Answer (score 2):

Not certain if the code is posted to OP correctly at `.bind().click()`? The issue is the code attaches an additional `click` event at each call to `getImgTrashEvents`, `showPresentImages`, and `uploadImages`.

Instead you can define the `click` event outside of `getImagTrashEvents`, and if necessary call `.click()` to dispatch the event instead of attaching another event handler to the jQuery object.

```
$('.image-demo').click(function(){
  if(confirm("Do you want to delete this image?")){
    //Do something to delete image
  }
});

function getImgTrashEvents(){
  $('.image-demo').click()
}
```